# How to handle data shared by many objects

Tags: c#, oop

I’m hitting a recurring situation with OOP and I’m wondering what the best way to handle it is. The issue is classes which have data that will be identical across many of their instances.

For example, say I wanted to make a road simulation of all the cars in NA. I would want a class for cars, with potentially hundreds of variables to store mechanical function. Some of this data would be unique to each car object, such as fuel level, temperature, ect. Other data would be consistent across all car objects of a specific model/year, such as horsepower, torque, braking speed, ect. All 2015 Honda Civics for instance would have the same horsepower (I know not accurate), but different fuel levels.

My problem is how to handle these shared values and still have my object specific values too. My ideas:

**Idea A:** create a sort of prefab object for each model/year and copy from these each time I make a car object. The primary issue with this is inefficient use of memory; say I have 50 vars tied to the model/year, I then have 100,000 2015 Honda Civics. That’s 5,000,000 stored values, most of which is duplicate because each 2015 Civic is storing exactly the model/year info.

**Idea B:** create some kind of database that stores the specs of each vehicle, then each instance would just need a reference or pointer to its respective vehicle in the database. The issue I have with this is it seems I would need parallel class trees, one for instance data, the other for the shared model data.

So I'm wondering what are my options for handling data that will be identical across a group of objects of the same class? I apologize if my explanation is unclear or thought process odd.

Comment: Constants or getter-only properties are not allocating any memory. The architecture questions are better to be asked at [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern for this exact issue proposed by the gang of four.

Flyweight: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

> A flyweight is an object that minimizes memory usage by sharing as much data as possible with other similar objects; it is a way to use objects in large numbers when a simple repeated representation would use an unacceptable amount of memory.

Even better explanation and examples can be found here: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/flyweight

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! Figured there must be a formalized best practice as it seems like it'd be a common issue but didn't know where to look.

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help. If the answers suits your needs, please accept it too.